# Why my substring is not being saved in 'st1' in a for loop but when I'm trying to print each value of st1 in loop it is working?

Tags: c, string, substring

Why in the `for` loop the value of `st1` is not saved ie: when I'm printing `st1` nothing is being printed?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char s[40] = "Who are you to tell me that I can not code?";
    char st1[15];

    for (int i = 2; i < 9; i++) {
        st1[i] = s[i];
        printf("%c", s[i]);
    }
    printf("\n Now Printing the Whole at once \n");
    printf("%s", st1);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the Output.....

```
o are y
 Now Printing the Whole at once

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.052 s
Press any key to continue.
```

Comment: You don't have a null terminator on `st1`, so it's not formally a string. Though that doesn't appear to be enough to fix this issue.

Comment: You also didn't initialize the array, so the first two characters are "random" (which may include 0)

Comment: Good point. So I guess you just learned that indices are usually closely coupled to one particular collection. The indices you use to read from `s` (`2..<9`) are different from the indices you want to use to write to `s` (`0..<7`).

Comment: @131MohammadUbaida:  you can accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score. You will be able to upvote once you get enough reputation.

Answer (score 1):

This loop

```
for (int i = 2; i < 9; i++) {
    st1[i] = s[i];
```

reads from `s` at indices [2, 8], but also writes to `st1` at indices [2, 8]. This means indices [0, 1] and [9, 14] of `st1` contain *indeterminate* values, having never been initialized. Reading these values is a form of [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior).

Use a separate index to place values from the start of `st1`, and make sure to [null-terminate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte) the result.

```
int j = 0;

for (int i = 2; i < 9; i++) {
    st1[j++] = s[i];
    printf("%c", s[i]);
}

st1[j] = '\0';
```

---

Aside: this initializer, being of type `char [44]`, is too long for the array being initialized.

```
char str[40] = "Who are you to tell me that I can not code?";
```

```
XXX.c:5:18: warning: initializer-string for char array is too long
    char s[40] = "Who are you to tell me that I can not code?";
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Use an empty size declarator to have the array automatically sized to match its initializer.

```
char str[] = "Who are you to tell me that I can not code?";
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code `st[0]` and `st[1]` are never set, so printing the string with `printf` has undefined behavior. `st[0]` probably happens to be a null byte, so `printf` prints nothing.

You should use a different index into `st1` and set a null byte at the end.

Beware also that `s` is not null terminated either because it has exactly 40 characters so no space for a null terminator byte.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char s[] = "Who are you to tell me that I can not code?";
    char st1[15];
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 2; i < 9; i++) {
        st1[j++] = s[i];
        printf("%c", s[i]);
    }
    st1[j] = '\0';

    printf("\nNow Printing the whole at once\n");
    printf("%s\n", st1);
    return 0;
}
```